# Word 2007 formatting window keeps coming up

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I'm editing a table in a word document and I don't understand why if I delete a text this formatting box always pop-up.

how can i get rid of this? 
Please see attached picture:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you have track changes being used at the moment. Either you or a previous owner turned on that function.

If you turn that off, that box will no longer pop up. [This](http://www.fgcu.edu/support/office2007/word/changes.asp) is a link about tracking your changes in Word 2007.

Comment: yes it's turned on. but before that it was already turned on. I wanted to edit the sentence and to show that it is crashed out how can you do this?

Comment: Sorry if you didn't understand the answer. What I meant was, you need to turn Track Changes off. Also, I am not quite sure by what you meant in the following statement. "I wanted to edit the sentence and to show that it is crashed out"

Comment: I just replied,stuck with work. So that means if I delete a text I should turn off the Track Changes?

Comment: Here is an idea for you. Save another copy of the file you are trying to edit. Then turn off "Track Changes." Then, see if that is what you are trying to accomplish. If it is, the answer I provided on Dec 29 '10 at 19:15 would have been correct. You have Track Changes turned on. You need to turn it off. That is all...

Comment: Hi David thanks I will try this again ok? and will let you know if this is what I wanted. Thanks

Comment: @tintincute, the reason I said to make a copy of the file before turning track changes off is to ensure that we will not screw anything up in the original file. accidents happen, and I want to make sure the preservation of the original file is met so nothing bad will happen. If you are wanting to show the a word is crossed out... there are other ways of doing that than with Track Changes, such as the "strike through" option under the fonts. Simply highlight the word(s), right-click, click fonts, and check the strike through box.

Comment: @David: Thank you for the explanation. :-)

Answer (score 3):

If the problem is just with making them go away (rather than stopping Track Changes), try:

```
Review tab -> Balloons -> Show all revisions inline
```

Answer (score 1):

To hide the balloons telling you about formatting, do the following:

```
Review tab -> Balloons -> Formatting
```

To stop tracking formatting altogether do the following:

```
Review tab -> Track Changes -> Change Tracking Options -> Uncheck "Track Formatting"
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Get rid of tracked changes and comments, once and for all](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/get-rid-of-tracked-changes-and-comments-once-and-for-all-HA001098388.aspx) :

1. On the Review band, click `Show Markup`, and then make sure that a check mark appears next to each of the following items :

   - Comments
   - Insertions and Deletions
   - Ink
   - Formatting
   - Reviewers (Point to Reviewers and make sure that `All Reviewers` is selected.)
2. On the Reviewing toolbar, click the arrow below `Accept` [image], and then click `Accept All Changes in Document`.